# read / write on socket descriptors linux c

Tags: sockets, client

I am trying to send the contents of a file from the server to the client , I am reading the file line by line using fgets and writing to the socket descriptor line by line , on the client side , i am in an a while loop , reading the sent contents.I am not being able to terminate the server sending sequence , i.e the client keeps reading the buffer and the next program line is not executed , I think thers something wrong with my way of sending or recieving . here is the code :

```
server :
filefd = fopen("clients.txt","a+");
          while(fgets(filcont,300,filefd) != NULL)
           {// write whole file contents to client
            n=write(newsockfd,filcont,strlen(filcont));
            if(n==0) break;
            memset(filcont,'\0',300);
           }
         fclose(filefd);


client side :
while(n>0){
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1);
            if(n==0) break;
            printf("%s\nbytes read :%d \n",buffer,n);
            memset(buffer,'\0',256);
            }
```

printf("Enter peer name ( except yours ) to send connection request : \n");
the above line ( printf , peer name doesnot get executed until i terminate the server)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out , I sent the file contents from the server using fread instead of fgets ( line by line ) and used a single read() at the client . this was the quick fix.
But I also figured out another technique when in case you have to compulsorily use fgets , where the while loop at the client side makes the socket nonblocking for read and then blocking again , the code is pasted below.

```
flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);     
while(n>0){
          n = read(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1);
          if(n==0) break;
          if(n==-1) printf("\nNon blocking read failed congrats");
            printf("%s\n",buffer);
          memset(buffer,'\0',256);
          }
          printf("\nbytes read :%d \n",n);
          val = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
          flags = O_NONBLOCK;
          val &= ~flags;  // makes it blocking again
          fcntl(sockfd,F_SETFL,val);
```

The code from stackoverflow was refered to make the socket blocking